# Kramdown not showing in heroku (Rails app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, markdown, kramdown

I am using gem kramdown, locally is working, but not in production. Here are the results locally:

```
content: "~~~ ruby\r\ndef what?\r\n  42\r\nend\r\n~~~",

kramdown_to_html(subthema.content.html_safe)
=> "<div class=\"language-ruby highlighter-coderay\"><div 
class=\"CodeRay\">\n  <div class=\"code\"><pre><span 
style=\"color:#080;font-weight:bold\">def</span> <span 
style=\"color:#06B;font-weight:bold\">what?</span>\n  <span 
style=\"color:#00D\">42</span>\n<span style=\"color:#080;font-
weight:bold\">end</span>\n</pre></div>\n</div>\n</div>\n"
```

As you see, the piece of code is translated into right HTML, every code-word is within a span and every span has its own class (then with CSS you give the styling).

In production though, here are the results, doing exactly the same:

```
irb(main):010:0> subthema.content.html_safe
=> "~~~ ruby\r\ndef what?\r\n  42\r\nend\r\n~~~"

irb(main):011:0> kramdown_to_html(subthema.content)
=> "<pre><code class=\"language-ruby\">def what?\n  42\nend\n</code>
</pre>\n"
```

As you see, the span tags are not there. In Heroku, Kramdown just achieves to create pre and code tagsm but not the spans.

Any help in this topic?

Thanks in advance.